# Making a Next statement into a Loop statement in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, loops

Hey everyone. My friend and I are re-learning Visual Basic, and we are stumped on this bit of code.

```
For intAsterisks As Integer = 0 To intLine - 1
  lblAsterisks.Text = lblAsterisks.Text + "*"
Next
```

We need to be able to make that from a For Next code into a Do Loop code. Could anyone assist us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would ask the question "Why do you need to convert it?"

```
Dim i as Integer = 0
Do While i < intLine
    lblAsterisks.Text = lblAsterisks.Text + "*"
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dim intAsterisks as integer = 0
Do While intAsterisks < intLine
    'Do stuff
    intAsterisks = intAsterisks + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dim i as integer
Private sub command1_click()
  For i = 0 to 30 Step 1
  Print (i)
  next 
end sub
```